# Drawing a flat bottom triangle, results in flat top triangle

Tags: c++, graphics

I'm trying to draw a flat bottom triangle, but its drawn as flat top triangle.
I would like to know what I'm doing wrong, in terms of math

here is my code

```
void Rasterizer::DrawBottomTriangle(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Color color)
{
    int temp_x;
    // test order of x1 and x2
    if (x2 < x1)
    {
        temp_x = x1;
        x1 = x2;
        x2 = temp_x;
    } //

    float dxy_left = (float)(x2 - x0) / (y2 - y0);
    float dxy_right = (float)(x1 - x0) / (y1 - y0);

    // set starting and ending points for edge trace
    float xs = x0;
    float xe = x0;

    // draw each scanline
    for (int y = y0; y >= y1; y--)
    {
        // draw a line from xs to xe at y in color c
        DrawLine(color, (int)xs, y, color, (int)xe, (int)y);
        // move down one scanline
        xs += dxy_left;
        xe += dxy_right;
    } // end for y
}
```

Comment: Just based on the title: most people learn coordinates counting from the bottom, computer graphics often count from the top.

Comment: If I count from the top, the loop won't be executed at all

Comment: What @BoBTFish is getting at is, are you sure that y increases as you move upwards? Often, higher y means further down, in which case you're already starting from the top.